# How to make Gnome's "Activities" bar always visible?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I just installed Gnome, and when I click on "Activities" a convenient bar shows up from the left, allowing me to switch to other applications. Unfortunately, the bar hides as soon as I choose an application.

How to make this bar always visible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. With Firefox go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/
2. Allow the web page's Firefox integration
3. On the web page, toggle the switch to "On"
4. Refresh the web page
5. A "Settings" icon has appeared, click it
6. Toggle "Intelligent autohide" to "Off"

[image: Dash to dock autohide]

Result:

[image: Gnome Activities bar]

Comment: You might want to also mention that one can change where it is positioned (on the left, right or bottom of the screen).

Comment: what is meant by step 2: Allow the web page's Firefox integration
I see no where on the web page where this is mentioned.

Comment: @RichardHartley was also confused about step 2, but figured it out. There is a small tool icon in the upper-right part of the extension web-page. Click on it and you get the `Dash to Dock` configuration window

Comment: follow the 4th step, toggle the switch on and refresh the web page, then the Dash to Dock switch back to off again. No "Settings" icon appeared.

Comment: Stinks that something so important as this, is an extension and that you must go back to its website to edit its settings.

Answer (score 2):

1. install from terminal `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock -y`
2. restart `sudo reboot` or relogin
3. search in "activities" for "tweaks"
4. in "Extensions" tab activate "Dash to dock" [Dash to dock activation and config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrrN8.jpg)
5. click on gear left of activation slide switch to change position or
   autohide

Comment: In Debian I had to search for "Extensions" in the apps, but thanks for the help!