# How to get Windows-like list of open apps/files/terminals etc on bottom of screen for navigation

Tags: navigation

The reason is <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll</kbd> and click is a lot of work for navigating the stuff I have open.

I’m using Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.

Comment: Please add which Ubuntu release version and flavour (desktop environment) you use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are in Gnome desktop (the main Ubuntu) because in Xfce, KDE, etc, the feature you are asking for is already in place.

So, you want the dock always visible: [How to make Gnome's "Activities" bar always visible?](https://askubuntu.com/q/792180/47206).

As for having it at the bottom of the screen: [How to shift side bar (Ubuntu dock) to bottom on Ubuntu 17.10 and later](https://askubuntu.com/q/966927/47206).

It looks like a duplicate of two questions.